# Can not access imported module from inside Python function

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a Django web app and app trying to make a script in the project directory that will create some random instances of a model (Person).  For some reason, I can't access any of my import statements. I can't even use the simple 'Random' module that is built in. I keep getting an error saying `'NameError: name 'random' is not defined'.`  I am running this script inside of my Django project, so I am running the script by the following command: `python manage.py shell < insert_into_database.py`

I have the following code:

```
import io
import random
import string

domains = ["hotmail.com", "gmail.com", "aol.com", "mail.com", 
"yahoo.com"]

letters = string.ascii_lowercase[:12]

def get_random_email(domains, letters):
    # length of each email address
    length = 10
    random_domain = random.choice(domains)
    random_name = ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(length))
    random_email = [random_name + '@' + random_domain for i in range(1)]

# Create 1000 random records
for i in range(1000):
    email = get_random_email(domains, letters)
```

Comment: I run the code and get no error. Could you please provide the stack trace? As there is nothing related to django in your code snippet, will you get error with running just `python insert_into_database.py`?

Comment: If I put the import statement inside the method definition, then it runs.  Once I put the statement at the top, for some reason Python won't recognize it.